# Display view as inside app notification in TableView Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, tableview, xib

I'm trying to display a View every time that I receive a remote push notification with the app in foreground. It works fine in View Controllers , but not for table view controllers. I couldn't find a way to get Y position for the currently visible cells.

Obs.: Would be even better if someone knows how to make it shows always over the Nav bar and not at the content view.

**EDIT:**
Follow some code:

```
 //Return the current VC that the user is seeing
    func getTopVC()->UIViewController?{
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        if application.applicationState == .active {
            if let topVC = UIApplication.getTopViewController() {
                return topVC
            }
        }
        return nil
    }


//Animation that shows XIB sliding down from outside the VC to Y = 0
    func animateXib(xibToAnimate: ApNotificationsXibView){
        let animationTime = 0.3
        let originalFrame = xibToAnimate.frame
        let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = [.allowUserInteraction]

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationTime, delay: 0, options: options, animations: {
            xibToAnimate.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: originalFrame.width, height: originalFrame.height)
        }) { (isEntryAnimationDone) in

            //SECOND ANIMATION TO SLIDE UP
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationTime, delay: 3.0, animations: {
                xibToAnimate.frame = originalFrame
            }) { (done) in
                xibToAnimate.removeFromSuperview()
            }

        }
    }

//Pre set some values, Add XIB on the current VC SubView and animate it
func displayNotificationXib(sendersName: String, sendersImage: UIImage, textToShow:String, connectionType: ApUserConnection.ConnectionType?, action: ApNotificationsXibView.TypeNotification, originUserId:String){
        if(isShowingXIB == false){
            if let vcToShowXib = self.getTopVC(){
                let xib = self.prepareXibToAdd()
                if let connect = ApActiveConnectionsServices.sharedInstance.getLocalConnectionWithId(with: originUserId){
                    xib.setValues(title: sendersName, sendersImage: sendersImage, body: textToShow, action: action, originId: originUserId, connect: connect)
                }
                vcToShowXib.view.addSubview(xib)
                animateXib(xibToAnimate: xib)
            }
        }
}





    //EXTENSION of UIApplication that get the current VC that the user is seeing
    class func getTopViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return getTopViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)

        } else if let tab = base as? UITabBarController, let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return getTopViewController(base: selected)

        } else if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return getTopViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
```

[image: View Controller]

[image: Table View Controller]

Comment: How do you show that view in tableViewController? Show us some codes.

Comment: I basically have an extension of UIApplication that always returns me the VC that the user is seeing. Based on that I just add the xib to the subview to a negative Y value and animate it to Y = 0.

Comment: @MarcusRohden Get the navigation controller of that VC and add the subview to that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the custom view over the navigation bar, add the view to the navigation controller instead of adding it to the view controller or the table view controller.

```
let customView = //...
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(customView)
```